# Temporary SQlite malformed pragma / disk image

Tags: python, database, sqlite

We use SQLite databases to store the results coming out of data analysis pipelines. The database files sit on our high performance scale-out filestore which is connected to the same switch as our cluster nodes to ensure a good connection.

However recently I've been having trouble querying the database via python. This is particularly the case when many jobs are trying to query the database at once. I get error messages such as

```
sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (primary_digest_joint) - index primary_digest_joint already exists
```

or

```
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

Note that these jobs are only reading the database, not writing to it (nothing is writing to the database), which I thought should be fine with SQLite.

Generally if I stop the pipeline, I can access the database fine and it appears to be perfectly intact. If I restart the pipeline again a number of jobs will successfully complete before I get the error again.

Any idea why this is happening or what can be done to stop it? Is there any chance that the database is actually being damaged, even though I seems to be fine, and running a PRAGMA integrity_check doesn't suggest anything is wrong.

Comment: You say the analysis pipeline stores its results in databases. Then you say nothing is writing to the database. Which one is true?

Comment: The database has been created historically from a pipeline, but nothing is writing to the database anymore. Its my own database, I am running no processes and no other user has access to the directory.

Comment: This looks as if your filestore is buggy.

Comment: I do hope not - its just about the most expensive storage solution is possible to buy. I wonder how we could test this.

Comment: SQLite just reads data from the database file. You could try running `md5sum` on it while the pipeline is running, but it's possible that only random accesses or file locking are broken.